# Creating Permanent Textbox on an Excel Userform

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

So I am creating a tool and user guide for my client. I am attempting to integrate the user guide into Excel in the form of a Userform. My first attempt was to insert these as images of the word document, however, if the user guide is ever updated that could mean a lot of work for anyone to update the userform as well. So I was looking to see if I could have a button for the user to click that would clear the userform and recreate it dynamically any time the User Guide is updated. My issue is that when I run my code the textboxes I create which contain the text from the user guide disappear after the userform is closed.

Do I have to have a set number of textboxes or can this be dynamic in the case that the user ever adds a new section to the user guide? Can I create textboxes that stay on the userform once it is closed?

My code is below:

```
    For i = 1 To totPara
        If wrdDoc.Paragraphs(i).Style = wrdDoc.Styles("Heading 1") Or wrdDoc.Paragraphs(i).Style = wrdDoc.Styles("Heading 2") Then
            headerCtr = headerCtr + 1
            If headerCtr = 2 Then
                labelCtr = labelCtr + 1
                Set tempTxt = Nothing
                Set tempTxt = userGuide.Controls.Add("Forms.TextBox.1", "Test" & labelCtr, True)
                With tempTxt
                    .Height = 276
                    .Width = 288
                    .Top = 54
                    .Left = 42
                    .MultiLine = True
                End With

                tempTxt.Text = wrdDoc.Paragraphs(i).Range.Text & Chr(13)
            ElseIf headerCtr > 2 Then
                Exit For
            End If
        ElseIf labelCtr <> 0 Then
            tempTxt.Text = tempTxt.Text & wrdDoc.Paragraphs(i).Range.Text & Chr(13)
        End If
    Next i
```

For right now I set it to create a new textbox only when `headerCtr` is equal to 2 for testing but eventually I would like to create a new textbox for each of the 9 sections.

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: I would take a look at this: http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: how is this not a legitimate question? I am creating textboxes all I want to know is if there is a way for them to be permanently attached to a userform and not disappear when the userform is closed.

Comment: Did I say it was not a legitimate question?  Did you read the link?

Comment: I immediately got defensive when reading `If you’re reading this, odds are good it’s because I or someone else linked here from your StackOverflow question shortly before it was closed and deleted.`

Comment: It also says "if you're reading this and you are not in that position".  Consider yourself the latter.  Anyway, the rest of the article shows how you can break down your code to find out exactly where the problem lies.  I find it to be very useful.

Comment: Any controls you add when the form is loaded will be removed when it's closed. If you want permanent controls then you need to manipulate the Designer which will mean the users must have trusted access to the VBA project in their security settings. I'd suggest finding another way - either hyperlinks to the doc itself or a .chm help file.

Comment: ^ that's all I was looking for. Honestly, didn't even think about hyperlinks to the doc, love that idea. thank you

Comment: If your client has www server I would make the manual i HTML and with one Application.FollowHyperlink attached to button it works. The great advantage of this is that you do not have to update your application to update help.

Answer (score 0):

You have the option Hide the userform instead of Close the userform. When it is hidden the textboxes can still be accessed from the calling form.

```
Dim frm1 As frmMainInput
Set frm1 = New frmMainInput
frm1.tbProjectNumber.Value = iProject_Number
frm1.txtDocsInUse.Text = sDocsInUse
frm1.Show

If frm1.Proceed = False Then
   GoTo Local_Exit
End If

iProject_Number = CInt(frm1.tbProjectNumber.Value)
```

Eventually call frm.close and set frm = Nothing

In the UserForm:

```
     Private Sub cmdCancel_Click()
        Proceed = False
        Me.Hide
    End Sub        
    Private Sub cmdOK_Click()
        Proceed = True
        Me.Hide
    End Sub
```

No clue about the refreshing images etc.c